# Find elements with same date and sum values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with example values

```
[
    {name:"Name1",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"33", realValue:"55"},
    {name:"Name2",date:"2018-08-03", optimalValue:"17", realValue:"23"},
    {name:"Name3",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"23", realValue:"12"},
    {name:"Name4",date:"2018-08-04", optimalValue:"12", realValue:"11"},
]
```

I want to find in this array element with same date and sum values in `optimalValue` and `realValue` and have similar array like this:

```
[
    {date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"56", realValue:"77"},
    {date:"2018-08-03", optimalValue:"17", realValue:"23"},
    {date:"2018-08-04", optimalValue:"12", realValue:"11"},
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? could you share the code that you have so far please?

Comment: Why `realValue:"77"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele because 55+12 = 77 sum values in same date

Comment: 55 + 12 is not 77 ...

Comment: @PiotrBieszczad that math you know is not from Earth `(:`

Comment: @all my bad sorry :) 67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and sum the values and the function `Object.values` to extract the desired array.

```js
let array = [{name:"Name1",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"33", realValue:"55"},{name:"Name2",date:"2018-08-03", optimalValue:"17", realValue:"23"},{name:"Name3",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"23", realValue:"12"},{name:"Name4",date:"2018-08-04", optimalValue:"12", realValue:"11"},],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {name, date, optimalValue, realValue}) => {
      a[date] = (a[date] || {date, optimalValue: 0, realValue: 0});
      a[date].realValue = String(Number(a[date].realValue) + Number(realValue));
      a[date].optimalValue = String(Number(a[date].optimalValue) + Number(optimalValue));
      return a;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The `optimalValue` and `realValue` is string type in the output mentioned by OP

Comment: @ankitAgarwal but it should be a number. There is no sense in it being a string.

Comment: @JonasW. you should answer based on what OP has shown. Also why doesn't it make sense? OP might require that as string as in input array. See the input array isn't that contain a string value

Comment: @JonasW. you're right, however, probably the OP needs those values as String.

Comment: This works perfectly ... I just modified it for Numbers instead of String :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use a hashtable to find / group duplicates:

```
const hash = {}, result = [];

for(const { date, name, optimalValue, realValue } of input) {
  if(!hash[date]) 
      result.push(hash[date] = { date, name, optimalValue: 0, realValue: 0 });
  hash[date].realValue +=+ realValue;
  hash[date].optimalValue +=+ optimalValue;
}
```

Comment: That's a Map, and you could also use the built-in Map.

Comment: @sandro sure but there is no difference here.

Comment: In a hashtable you would only save the entries, no values associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that. Since you require `optimalValue` and `realValue` as a string type, you can convert those into string after summing up the value using `parseInt()`:

```js
var arr = [
{name:"Name1",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"33", realValue:"55"},
{name:"Name2",date:"2018-08-03", optimalValue:"17", realValue:"23"},
{name:"Name3",date:"2018-08-01", optimalValue:"23", realValue:"12"},
{name:"Name4",date:"2018-08-04", optimalValue:"12", realValue:"11"},
];

var res = arr.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  var existObj = acc.find(item => item.date === obj.date);
  if(existObj){
    existObj.realValue = (parseInt(existObj.realValue) + parseInt(obj.realValue)).toString();
     existObj.optimalValue = (parseInt(existObj.optimalValue) + parseInt(obj.optimalValue)).toString();
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(res);
```